# How to escape "# and #" in raw string literals

Tags: rust, escaping, multiline

I wanna do this

```rust
let mystr = r#"
Id("#1#")
Id("#2#")
Id("#3#")
"#;
```

Which does not compile, since I need to somehow escape the `"#` and the `#"` occurences. but I don't know how to...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the problem with your approach is that your raw string contains sequence that is used for terminating raw string. What you need to do is add another `#` on start and end of raw string. Like this:

```
let mystr = r##"
Id("#1#")
Id("#2#")
Id("#3#")
"##;
```

Notice second opening and closing `#`.
Output is:

```
Id("#1#")
Id("#2#")
Id("#3#")
```

You can check it out here on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=effb865460bcba511c0ec1508030faea).

Check out [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals), especially this part:

> Raw string literals do not process any escapes. They start with the character U+0072 (r), followed by fewer than 256 of the character U+0023 (#) and a U+0022 (double-quote) character. **The raw string body can contain any sequence of Unicode characters and is terminated only by another U+0022 (double-quote) character, followed by the same number of U+0023 (#) characters that preceded the opening U+0022 (double-quote) character.**

Comment: Thanks! Note to self: Read docs more carefully! they even had a similar example with: "r##"foo #"# bar"##;                // foo #"# bar"

Comment: Ruts docs are... awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an arbitrary number of hashes as string delimiters, as long as this number of hashes don't appear in the string itself. [Like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=631521b424efd61a9260496326babd06):

```
let mystr = r##"
    Id("#1#")
    Id("#2#")
    Id("#3#")
"##;
```